# How can I get data in json array by ID

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, json

I have a problem, may you help me!
I have a json array:

```
"category" : [
{
    id: 1,
    product: [{id : product_1, type : ball}] 
},
{
    id : 2,
    product :[{id : product_2, type : pen}]
}
]
```

My problem is: if i have a link such as: http://test/category/1 then , How can I do to get product information by category with id = 1 ? 
Thanks for any suggestion :)

Answer (score 16):

This is a way to do it in one line and without using for:

```
function filterById(jsonObject, id) {return jsonObject.filter(function(jsonObject) {return (jsonObject['id'] == id);})[0];}
```

Then if you want to get, for example, the object with id=2, you just use:

```
var selectedObject = filterById(yourJson['category'], 2);
```

And then selectedObject will get this value, as per your example:

```
{
    id : 2,
    product :[{id : product_2, type : pen}]
}
```

There is a downside: Old browsers, such as IE8, don't support filter() so you need to add this polyfill code for old browser compatibility:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter#Polyfill

Answer (score 13):

Assuming your data structure looks like this:

```
var data = {
    "category" : [
    {
        id: 1,
        product: [{id : product_1, type : ball}] 
    },
    {
        id : 2,
        product :[{id : product_2, type : pen}]
    }
    ]
}
```

Then, you can find the item in the category array with id == 1 by searching through the array like this:

```
function findId(data, idToLookFor) {
    var categoryArray = data.category;
    for (var i = 0; i < categoryArray.length; i++) {
        if (categoryArray[i].id == idToLookFor) {
            return(categoryArray[i].product);
        }
    }
}

var item = findId(data, 1);
// item.id, item.type
```

Comment: its old. but why not mark as an answer? worked perfect.

Answer (score 3):

If you save your array of categories in `categories` JS variable, you can filter this array based on simple JavaScript (with no jQuery) like that:

```
var result = categories.filter(function(element){
    if (element.id == 2){
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
});
```

and then in `result[0].product` you will have array of products that are within specific category.

See [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YwtrB/1/) for a proof.

PS. `filter()` method is not available in all browsers, you may need to apply some code that will make it available if needed and not found. Here is some article on Mozilla Developers Network on the details of `filter()` and the code you need to make it work on old browsers: [MDN: `filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).

Answer (score 0):

I think the OP wants to **retrieve corresponding data from url**.

So the first step is map the url to identifier

```
var urlParts = window.location.href.split(/\//)
//window.location.href = http://domain.com/category/1
// urlParts = ['http:', '', 'domain.com', 'category', '1']
var id = urlParts.pop();
var category = urlParts.pop();
```

Then you retrive the data from JSON string with `JSON.parse`:

```
var data = JSON.parse('{"category" : [{"id": 1, "product": [{"id" : "product_1", "type" : "ball"}] }, {"id" : 2, "product" :[{"id" : "product_2", "type" : "pen"}] } ]}');

//The data structure
// {"category" : [
//   {"id": 1, "product" : 
//     [
//       {"id" : "product_1", "type" : "ball"}
//     ]},

//   {"id" : 2, "product" :
//     [
//       {"id" : "product_2", "type" : "pen"}
//     ]} 
// ]}
```

At last, you can retrive the data similar @jfriend00's post with `id` and `category`

```
function findId(data, idToLookFor) {
    var categoryArray = data.category;
    for (var i = 0; i < categoryArray.length; i++) {
        if (categoryArray[i].id == idToLookFor) {
            return(categoryArray[i].product);
        }
    }
}

var item = findId(data.category, id);
// item.id, item.type
```

Answer (score 0):

You might have found the answer, but if you haven't you can simply use the logical **OR** (`||`) operator.

In your case, you can use jQuery's `ajax()` method.  To grab your product based on `id`s just use the below simple logic:

```
var prodID1 = 1, prodID2 = 2;
if(this.id == prodID || this.id == prodID2) {
  //write your JSON data, etc.
  //push to array, etc.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
"category" : [
{
    id: 1,
    product: [{id : product_1, type : ball}] 
},
{
    id : 2,
    product :[{id : product_2, type : pen}]
}
]
```

In this scenario I recommend, that you get the array from the Json response using the key. For example if your json response name is : "data" then do "data.category" which will give you an array to loop through.
Then

```
const allProducts = data.category;
allProducts .forEach((element) => {
//here id is your own id by which you want to compare against the json object
      if (element.id == id) {
response.status(200).json(element) 
//or you can return this element and capture it for any other operation you desire to do 
                            }
});
```