# Passing an object at runtime to a javascript function

Tags: javascript, jquery

At runtime, I have Javascript create html and I want to bind an object on them to pass onto a function for later.

Something like this:

```
var projects = //(json object)
projects.forEach(function(p) {
   $("#container").append("<div onclick=handleClick(p)></div>");
});

function handleClick(p) {
  //...
}
```

It seems like doing this makes `p` become the string `[object object]` instead of the actual Project object and using JQuery's built in $.click function is the same thing. I know I have to bind these elements to a function at runtime somehow.

What is the proper way to do something like this without excessive searching and DOM access?

Comment: You can use jQuery's `.data()` method to store the object against the element in question. Then in the click handler use `$(this).data()` to retrieve it. Read [the `.data()` doco](http://api.jquery.com/data/) and give it a try; come back if you still have trouble.

Comment: Handle the click on the parent and decide based on which div was clicked. If you have an id to identify which project was clicked, you can use that as a data attribute so you can identify

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create your content and set its click handler with JavaScript instead of inline HTML handlers.

```js
var projects = [{id: 1}, {id:2}, {id:3}];
projects.forEach(function(p) {
   $("#container").append($("<div>Test </div>").click(function(e){
       handleClick(p);
   }));
});

function handleClick(p) {
  console.log('Clicked project', p.id);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="container">
Content here
</div>
```

Note that a better alternative (because you only need a single handler and you don't have to worry about adding handlers later) would be to set a handler on the parent and you could use a data-pid attribute on each div that will let your handler find the correct project based on which div was clicked.

```js
$(() => {
  var projects = [{id: 1}, {id: 2}, {id: 3}];
  projects.forEach(function(p) {
    $("#container").append("<div class=clicky data-pid=" + p.id + ">Project " + p.id + " </div>");
  });
  $("#container").click('.clicky', (e) => {
    console.log('Clicked paragraph for ' + $(e.target).data('pid'));
  })

})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="container">
  Content
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! Just the solution I was looking for

Comment: .. though you are right with your 2nd example, since projects will be updated without page refresh, adding more handlers later seems like a bad idea. Will use your 2nd approach

Comment: I'm thinking about your second approach, but my objects are much more complex than yours and are nested within multiple json layers & arrays and I have to [search the json data file for the object from the id](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8163859/how-can-i-get-data-in-json-array-by-id) from what it seems like, which is what I want to avoid. Do you have any tips for this, or should I go with the second approach and rebind when new projects are created in the DOM?

Comment: My suggestion is use a single handler if possible. It can't be that expensive to search through your structure. If needed, create maps like  the answer you linked to